# Why in most of exercise of Linear Algerbra field involved is a subfield of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am studying Linear Algebra by Hoffman , they have written that reader should assume that field involved is a subfield of complex numbers , they have explained a reason beyond this by giving the argument of field of characterstic zero .can anyone explain regarding this ? Thanks

Comment: In page 2 of Hoffman-Kunze it is explicitly written that scalars can be taken from any field. Where *exactly* does the book require assuming working with a subfield of the complex? Perhaps it is in a special case?

Comment: @Timbuc see page 3 under example 4

Comment: They want to make things easier to beginners, according to their explanation. Most interesting *elementary* examples in linear algebra use fields of characteristic zero, and going into positive characteristics would require, I gather, a deviation from what they planned for the book, at least for the first chapters.

Comment: @Timbuc can you explain the argument given in book as $1+1+1....+1=0$ ...under example 4 .what is problem in doing this

Comment: No problem at all with that, but I guess the authors consider it can be a little too abstract and hard to grasp for beginners. BTW, I don't agree with them on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things we are used to doing in a field is division. For example, solving a quadratic equation $x^2 + px + q = 0$ involves dividing by $2$. However, if $1 + 1 = 0$, dividing by $2$ is not allowed, as $2 = 0$; it would be the same as saying $0$ has a multiplicative inverse, which can never happen in any ring where $0 \neq 1$.

Some concepts, like *skew-symmetric matrices*, do not mean the same thing in a field of characteristic $2$. Other concepts, like *positive-definite* (needed to define inner products) do not make sense unless one has an ordered subfield, which is never possible in a field of finite characteristic (you can define an order, but it doesn't "respect" the field operations).

It may seem strange that finite fields even exist, but they do, and in such a field (because they are finite):

$1\\
1+1\\
1+1+1$

et cetera, cannot ALL be different. If we denote $1 + 1 +\cdots + 1\ (k\ \text{times})$ as $k\cdot 1$, then if:

$k\cdot 1 = m\cdot 1$, for $k < m \in \Bbb Z^+$ we have:

$0 = k\cdot 1 - k\cdot 1 = m\cdot 1 - k\cdot 1 = (m-k)\cdot 1$, and $m - k$ is an example of such an $n$.

It turns out that when this happens, for us to actually get a field, the smallest such positive $n$ must be a prime number, $p$. Vector spaces over such finite fields are often used in "coding" information, and error correction.

When first undertaking a study of linear algebra, assuming $F$ is a subfield of the complex numbers allows us to perform our usual "arithmetic" without fear of getting unusual results. Generalizing what is learned to an arbitrary field is usually not much harder, but one has to pay attention to any proof where one divided by a scalar, as there might be exceptions in a field of finite characteristic (these will often be pointed out in the text).

Comment: Great answer. I was thinking along these lines but couldn't formalize my thoughts nearly as well as you've explained.

Comment: @David can you give example where quadratic equation solving is screwed in some field

Comment: @David doesn't 1+1=2 varies with field

Comment: @K.Dutta No; $1+1$ is always the definition of $2$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom then how can 1+1=0

Comment: @K.Dutta nothing about the definition of $2$ (in an arbitrary field) says that $2\neq0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i havenot understood your point

Comment: @DavidWheeler I would add that we can't define a good notion of length (ie norm) in a finite field

Comment: @K.Dutta every field has an element that we call $1$, an element that we call $0$, and an operation that we call addition. When you "add" this "$1$" to itself, you get the element that we call "$2$". This "$2$" may or may not be the same element as $0$.